# CentOS 7 で MariaDB が採用された理由について

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

**CentOS7 導入を検討しているのですが、MariaDB が採用された理由は何でしょうか？**
・MySQLは完全なオープンソースではない？

---

**質問背景**
・MySQL使用継続を考えているのですが、MariaDB が今後標準となっていくのなら、このタイミングで切り替えた方が良いかも、と悩んでいます
・MySQLバージョンアップデートする際、バージョン間差異が結構あって苦労したので、「DB変更だとそれ以上に大変かも。なるべく避けたい」と思っているのですが……

---

**現在の環境**
・CentOS6
・MySQL5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOSはRHEL(RedHat Enterprise Linux)をベースにしたディストリビューションですので、正確にはRHELの意向に従った形になります。

mariaDBの誕生、及びRHELをはじめ多くのディストリビューションがmariaDBに移行したきっかけは、MySQLがSun Microsystemsと共にOracleに買収されたことにより、MySQLの今後に不安を感じたからだと言われています。

元々Oracleは商用DBを持っており、オープンソースのMySQLを引き取ったけどちゃんと今まで通りMySQLの面倒を見てくれるの？といったところでしょうか。

http://enterprisezine.jp/dbonline/detail/4220
https://japan.zdnet.com/article/35056719/